# gnu-screen does not clear all its contents upon leaving it

Tags: bash, centos, gnu-screen

I am using screen in bash under CentOS. After leaving a screen with Alt-a d, I am back in bash as expected. But there are remnants of the screen output left, in particular the status line (don't know if it's hardstatus or what). When I press Ctrl-l, the bash is cleared back to normal. I do not have this problem on other CentOS systems where I use the same .screenrc. How can I alleviate this problem? I would like screen to clear all its contents from bash when I press Alt-a d, otherwise it is very annoying because I can't visually detect if I am stil in the screen session or not.

My .screenrc is:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%= %3n %t%? [%h]%? %="
caption always "%= %-w%L>%{= BW}%n*%t%{-}%52<%+w %L="
altscreen
bind s
```

--
Software used:
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
CentOS (don't know which version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the properties of the terminal you are reverting to, not of screen. If you look up the xterm page, you will find this:

> In VT102 mode, there are escape sequences to activate and deactivate an alternate screen buffer, which is the same size as the display area of the window. When activated, the current screen is saved and replaced with the alternate screen. Saving of lines scrolled off the top of the window is disabled until the normal screen is restored. The termcap(5) entry for xterm allows the visual editor vi(1) to switch to the alternate screen for editing and to restore the screen on exit. A popup menu entry makes it simple to switch between the normal and alternate screens for cut and paste.

Thus, you need to set altscreen on on whatever type of terminal you are using.

Comment: I thought I have set altscreen, it is in my .screenrc which I quoted?! Or do you mean that I have to set altscreen elsewhere? Could you please let me know how I can set altscreen?

Comment: You have set altscreen inside screen. You need to set it for the terminal, not inside the screen session.

Comment: Ok, but *how* can I set altscreen for a terminal? I tried "altscreen", "altscreen on".. there does not seem to be such a command. I googled but only find referenced to altscreen within screen.

Comment: which type of term?

Comment: Terminal 0.4.8
Xfce Terminal Emulator

Comment: 1) Put "altscreen on" in your .screenrc 2) put in your .Xdefault or .Xresources these two lines, XTerm*titeInhibit: false, urxvt*secondaryScreen: true 3) oblige X to use these specs by issuing the command  xrdb -l .Xresources. This is how it's done by the book. If it doesn't work, then it's a bug. Let me know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11205/discussion-between-gojira-and-mariusmatutiae)